# Airflow - ValueError: cannot map over XCom with custom key while trying to use expand function in Dynamic Task Mapping

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I retrieve a dictionary from a task and one of the dictionary values is a list.
I am trying to perform Dynamic Task Mapping with expand() on that list.

However, I get this error:

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/AA_taskflowApi.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/mappedoperator.py", line 123, in ensure_xcomarg_return_value
    ensure_xcomarg_return_value(v)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/mappedoperator.py", line 118, in ensure_xcomarg_return_value
    raise ValueError(f"cannot map over XCom with custom key {key!r} from {operator}")
ValueError: cannot map over XCom with custom key 'nicks' from <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): get_name>
```

Here is my simple DAG:

```
@dag(dag_id='AA_TaskflowApi', 
     default_args=default_args, 
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
     schedule=None)
def hello_world_etl():

    @task(multiple_outputs=True)
    def get_name():
        nicknames=["Nickname1","Nickname2"]
        return {
            'name': 'Jerry',
            'nicks': nicknames
        }

    @task
    def print_nicks(nick):
        print(f"Processing nickname {nick}")   
    
    @task
    def print_all_nicks(nicks):
        print(f"Processing nicknames {nicks}")   

    name_dict = get_name()
    nicks=name_dict['nicks']
    
    #This Does NOT work - Causes DAG Import error
    print_nicks.expand(nick=nicks)

    # BUT This Works
    # print_all_nicks(nicks)    
greet_dag = hello_world_etl()
```

How can I use the list nicks to do dynamic task mapping successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `name_dict` is not available during compiling time, it's only available after executing the task during runtime. If you have a fixed format in the method `get_name` coming from an API for ex, you should transform the output and prepare the list in a new task

```py
import pendulum

from airflow.decorators import dag, task

default_args = {}


@dag(dag_id='AA_TaskflowApi',
     default_args=default_args,
     start_date=pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
     schedule=None)
def hello_world_etl():
    @task(multiple_outputs=True)
    def get_name():
        nicknames = ["Nickname1", "Nickname2"]
        return {
            'name': 'Jerry',
            'nicks': nicknames
        }

    @task
    def print_nicks(nick):
        print(f"Processing nickname {nick}")

    @task
    def get_nicks(name_dict):
        return  name_dict['nicks']

    name_dict = get_name()
    nicks = get_nicks(name_dict)

    print_nicks.expand(nick=nicks)


greet_dag = hello_world_etl()
```